# Show that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given there are 3 logical variables $p$, $q$ ,$r$. Show that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ is a tautology

And here is my steps: $\neg(p\rightarrow q) \land (q\rightarrow r) \lor (p\rightarrow r)$

What should I do in order to get rid of it? ps: I am studing from Discrete mathematics and its application 7th edition rosen thanks

Comment: The easiest way to show this is a tautology is by truth tables.

Comment: Yes but don't have to use truth table but using logcial equivlance

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{array}{cl}
&\left(p\Longrightarrow q\right) \land \left(q \Longrightarrow r\right) \Longrightarrow \left(p\Longrightarrow r\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \neg \left(\left(\neg p \lor q \right) \land \left(\neg q \lor r \right)\right)\lor \left(\neg p \lor r\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \neg \left(\neg p \lor q \right) \lor \left(\neg q \lor r \right)\lor \left(\neg p \lor r\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(p \lor \neg q\right)  \lor \left(\neg q \lor r\right) \lor \left(\neg p \lor r\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & \left(p \lor \neg p\right)  \lor \left(q \lor \neg q\right) \lor \left(r \lor \neg r\right) \\
\Longleftrightarrow & 1
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the truth tables just try to bring your formula to [conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) then apply appropriate theorem and you're done.